# Selenium in a web service - jar not loaded

Tags: java, web-services, selenium, webserver, selenium-webdriver

I tried to implement a web service in a bottom-up manner. First I created a dynamic web project and implemented a function that uses selenium. I then added the selenium-server-standalone-3.23.0.jar to the project's buildpath. Then I added the same jar file to the deployment assembly. Then I used the web service wizard to generate the web server and the client. After that I added the same selenium jar file to the WEB-INF/lib folder of the server and tried to run the function, the function returned this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:177)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:142)
at org.apache.axis.utils.cache.ClassCache.lookup(ClassCache.java:85)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getServiceClass(JavaProvider.java:428)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.initServiceDesc(JavaProvider.java:461)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.getInitializedServiceDesc(SOAPService.java:286)
at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.makeNewInstance(WSDDService.java:500)
at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getService(WSDDDeployment.java:427)
at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getService(FileProvider.java:231)
at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getService(AxisEngine.java:311)
at org.apache.axis.MessageContext.setTargetService(MessageContext.java:756)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper.invoke(URLMapper.java:50)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:239)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
... 42 more
```

Then I looked at the console and saw that it said:

```
May 21, 2013 8:45:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\sonkezeko3\WEB-INF\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

What is causing this? Should I use some other jar file? The code of the server is below:

```
package test.sonkezeko3;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class sonkezeko3 {
public String Ekobilet(String from, String to, String date) {

    //Firefox browser instantiation
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Loading the URL
    driver.get("http://www.amadeusepower.com/trek/portals/trek/default.aspx?Culture=en-US");


    WebElement radioOneway = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_rbFlightType_1"));
    radioOneway.click();

    waitForPageLoaded(driver);


    WebElement fromText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtSearch_txtFrom"));
    fromText.clear();
    fromText.sendKeys(from); 


    WebElement toText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtSearch_txtTo"));
    toText.sendKeys(to); 


    WebElement dateText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_txtDepartureDate_txtDate"));
    dateText.clear();
    dateText.sendKeys(date); 

    //Sign in button identification and click it
    WebElement searchbutton = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cph1_cph1_QuickSearchAll1_QuickFlightSearchControl1_btnSearch"));
    searchbutton.click();

    String page = driver.getPageSource();

    //Closing the browser
    driver.close();

    return page;

    }

    public static void waitForPageLoaded(WebDriver driver) {

        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
           public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
             return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
           }
         };

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
         try {
                 wait.until(expectation);
         } catch(Throwable error) {
                 System.out.println("exception yavrum");
         }
    } 

}
```

Comment: No answer? No one knows the cause of this? Or is the question unclear in any way?

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using standalone jars rather use [selenium-java-2.37.0.jar](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-java-2.37.0.zip) and try. It worked for me. Keep your `lib` folder inside `WEB-INF` only.